# Do movement restrictions end if country of origin gets added to green list?

Tags: covid-19, ireland

If at the time of my arrival in Ireland, the [Green List](https://www.gov.ie/en/publication/8868e-view-the-covid-19-travel-advice-list) does not contain the country I started my travels from and I start to [restrict my movements](https://www2.hse.ie/conditions/coronavirus/managing-coronavirus-at-home/if-you-live-with-someone-who-has-coronavirus.html#restrict), but before my 14 days restriction are over my country of origin is put on the list and it goes into effect, do my requirements to restrict my movements end the day the updated list goes into effect, or do only new arrivals from that  time on not require movement restrictions any more?

Comment: Not sure about Ireland, but in most countries you continue to be bound by the regulations that were in force when you arrived.  This makes more sense when you think about it in the other direction: if a country is removed from the green list, they don't slap you in quarantine halfway through.

Comment: @lambshaanxy Actually, at the very beginning of this pandemic (before a lockdown or any contraining legal framework was in place in my country of residence), I have actually been advised to self-isolate after the fact (returning from a country 4-5 days before it was considered dangerous, being asked to spend the last 3-4 days of a 14-day quarantine at home). Intuitively, this does make sense because prevalence or positivity rate on a given date reflects the circulation of the virus some time in the past and you could be most contagious a few days after any potential contact.

Comment: But if we ignore this and look at it from a purely legal point of view, what makes you think that in most countries you would be bound by the regulation that were in force when you arrived? It's more difficult to do anything if you are not testing and registering people at the border but on a theoretical level it's certainly possible for the regulations I am familiar with (it's phrased as "having been in area XYZ in the last X days” so if it kicks in before X days after you returned, you're formally covered).

Comment: @Relaxed This is policy in both Australia and Singapore, where quarantine is strictly enforced and changes in regulations take effect at a point in time for new arrivals.   Before the point, old rules apply (and continue to apply), after it, new ones do.  See eg. https://www.gov.sg/article/updates-to-border-measures-for-low-risk-countries-from-1-sep

Comment: @lambshaanxy I also found some European countries where this is explicitly handled in this way (Germany, the UK).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it stands (based on information I got from phone calls with the HSE and [Irish Citizens Information](https://www.citizensinformation.ie)) one is bound by the rules that were in place on entering the country, unless any official source would explicitly state otherwise - which so far has not been the case.

In short, if you're subject to restrictions of movements when you arrive, they stay in place even if the country is cleared in the meantime. Similarly, you won't have to go into movement restrictions if you came from a country on the Green List that is taken down from there within two weeks after your arrival.